# java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: argument type mismatch javafx

Tags: java, javafx-2

I am trying to add a ToolTip ui control to TableColumn of a TableView.
I am getting following exception. Please help.

```
SEVERE: Failed to load skin 'com.sun.javafx.scene.control.skin.TooltipSkin' for control Label[id=null, styleClass=tooltip]'123'
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: argument type mismatch
        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
```

Following is the code.

```
TableColumn<HomeDraftRequestModel, Long> revenueColId = (TableColumn) getReqForMyActionTableView()
            .getColumns().get(8);

    revenueColId.setCellFactory(new Callback<TableColumn<HomeDraftRequestModel, Long>, TableCell<HomeDraftRequestModel, Long>>() {
        @Override
        public TableCell<HomeDraftRequestModel, Long> call(
                TableColumn<HomeDraftRequestModel, Long> param) {
            Label label = new Label();

            return new TableCell<HomeDraftRequestModel, Long>() {
                @Override
                protected void updateItem(Long item, boolean empty) {
                    super.updateItem(item, empty);
                    if (empty) {
                        setGraphic(null);
                    } else {
                        label.setText(item + "");
                        Tooltip toopTip = new Tooltip(item + "");
                        Tooltip.install(label, toopTip);
                        label.setUnderline(true);
                        label.setCursor(Cursor.HAND);
                        label.setOnMouseEntered(new EventHandler<MouseEvent>() {
                            @Override
                            public void handle(MouseEvent arg0) {
                                label.setTooltip(toopTip);
                            }
                        });
                        setGraphic(label);
                    }
                }

            };
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

All the useful functionality in a `Label` is also defined directly in a `TableCell` (they are both subclasses of `Labeled`). So you can get rid of the label, and just call the methods directly on the `TableCell`. You also don't need the mouse listener: the tooltip knows when to display itself. Just call `setTooltip(...)` to enable it.

The following should work:

```
            protected void updateItem(Long item, boolean empty) {
                super.updateItem(item, empty);
                if (empty) {
                    setText(null);
                    setTooltip(null);
                } else {
                    setText(item + "");
                    Tooltip toolTip = new Tooltip(item + "");
                    setUnderline(true);
                    setCursor(Cursor.HAND);
                    setTooltip(toolTip);
                }
            }
```

I'm not entirely sure why you were getting the exception you were getting; but it should help to simplify the code and use something more "standard".